# How to handle callback URL path that is more than 1 location path (/fruits/apple) in ReactJs + ExpressJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, okta

So I've implemented **Okta** login with ReactJS which works perfectly fine. However when I try to host my ReactJs + ExpressJs. I can no longer render the call back properly due to the URL path is `/login/callback` *(As I understand, each `path` in individual route is always just 1 word like `/apple`, `/orange`. Instead of 2 words like `/fruits/apple`, `fruits/orange`)*

The problem here is, I need `<Route path="/login/callback" component={LoginCallback} />` to render/process the `LoginCallBack component` defined here. Because this component is part of the library component, it should perform further redirection.

Since the code cannot process login/callback, the component is not render and my website just stuck at the callback URL by OKTA.

##### ReactJs

App.js

```
Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      component={Home}
    />
    <Route path="/login/callback" component={LoginCallback} />  {/* Notice the path in this route? */}
    <SecureRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    <SecureRoute path="/message" component={message} />
    <SecureRoute path="/request" component={request} />
  </Switch>
</Security>
```

##### ExpressJS

Index.js

```
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './build')));

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/build/index.html'));  
});


app.get("/", ((req, res) => {
    res.render("index.html");
}));
```

Comment: Your problem is likely due to attempting to use a direct url when using React Router. See the following SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928372/5166365

Comment: @MichaelSohnen thx for the comment, looks like everyone is recommending to direct the page back to index.html. which is what I have did within my express.js actually, or did i miss anything you try to point out?

Comment: I'm familiar with auth0, but not with Octa in particular. In my case, I made an app with microsoft azure. When I specified the callback address, it was to the backend, NOT the frontend. After the callback was received, I used express `res.redirect` to go to index.html. Therefore, I am thoroughly confused why the callback is handled by your react app at all. Nevertheless, if you want to redirect to a particular component instead of just plain index.html, you can consider using a `HashRouter`. This way you can use a hash to formulate direct urls, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/#/login/callback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging, researching, trial and error... here's the solution.

## TLDR

Append `base` tag in index.html

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="/mysub-application1"/>
  ...
</head>
```

## Details

First of all, credit to this [medium post](https://dev-listener.medium.com/react-routes-nodejs-routes-2875f148065b).

According to poster's explanation why `base` tag is required...

> The reason for base tag requirement is because, when ever a nested URL is being directed to NodeJS to load, it would diligently use the `/mysub-application1/*` as a match and would try to load index.html from the asked path (example if the asked path is `mysub-application1/foo/bar` then the static resources would try to resolve from `mysub-application1/foo/bar` instead of `mysub-application1`, which causes 404 issues).

[image]